# Non-modal forms cannot be displayed in this host application from an ActiveX DLL, ActiveX Control, or Property Page

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, activex

How to Resolve following Error in .net

Non-modal forms cannot be displayed in this host application from an ActiveX DLL, ActiveX Control, or Property Page.

Answer (score 2):

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176468 for the details of the cause of this.  In particular, note the recommendation that the code in the ActiveX Control should have:

```
If App.NonModalAllowed Then
  frmModeless.Show vbModeless
Else
  frmModeless.Show vbModal
End If
```

If this is a third-party control that you do not have the source to, as far as I can tell, there is no easy workaround.  The only workaround I have found so far is to wrap the offending control within another control created with VB6, making sure that that control is compiled to an ActiveX .exe not an ActiveX .dll.

Comment: I am using same code in VB6.0 and trying to show form1 into VB.Net. But getting same ERROR "Non-modal forms cannot be displayed in this host application from an ActiveX DLL, ActiveX Control, or Property Page."

Any help please, its an urgent.