# non- Modal forms cannot be displayed in this application, in installshield

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, installshield

I have created a VB .NET command Line application, to call a Active X Dll. This displays a non-modal form. I run this application via installshield to execute on installation of the software. However I get the following error:

[image]

Making any modification to the VB6 code is not an option, so is there a way of calling non-modal forms from a VB .Net application.

Comment: I can't see any code.  A non-modal window requires a message loop (Application.Run) and an STA thread (`<STAThread>` attribute on Main).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  I can't imagine this design will be good from an installation reliability perspective.

Comment: This was just a test installer, everything works find using an Active X .exe, it looks more professional now without the cmd popping up. The reason why we had to do these things this way is because our Core application in written in VB6, and this installer has to interact with the our software on the client's machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post may answer some questions. From my understanding you aren't able to show a non-modal form from an ActiveX DLL, the two options are to either modify the DLL to show a modal form or to recompile it as an executable.

[Non-modal forms cannot be displayed in this host application from an ActiveX DLL, ActiveX Control, or Property Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975061/non-modal-forms-cannot-be-displayed-in-this-host-application-from-an-activex-dll)

The post mostly just links to this KB article http://support.microsoft.com/kb/176468

Comment: It worked...I created a Active X .exe, and used this to called the VB6 form from within my .NET application.